# does this exist as (std) module: cyclic iteration (a little like itertools.cycle) without intermediate memory allocation

Tags: python

Hi I'd like to have an iterator, that cyclically repeats a sequence.

I tend to go for cyclic_count_v3, but whanted to know whether I overlooked something in the existing python modules.

Below three implementations. So far I did not profile them, but would instinctively go for solution3 or if I'd put it into a library I'd go for
the last implementation.

Let's assume N may be a huge number and that I'd like to use as little RAM as possible.

My question is, whether I'm reinventing the wheel and this functionality exists already somewhere else.

```
import itertools

def cyclic_count_v1(N):
    # advantage: low memory
    # disadvantage: calculates modulo for each iteration
    #               and as pointed out by @chepner. 
    #               counter is growing infinitely
    for v in itertools.count():
        yield v % N

def cyclic_count_v2(N):
   # advantage: no modulo calculation
   # disadvantage: a copy of expanded range(N) is created
   return itertools.cycle(range(N))

def cyclic_count_v3(N):
    # advantage no modulo calculation
    # advantage no copy of range in RAM
    while True:
        for v in range(N):
            yield v
```

And last but not least another (more generic) implementation, with a different signature:

```
def cyclic_loop(iterfactory):
    while True:
        myiter = iterfactory()
        for v in myiter:
            yield v
```

It had to be called with:

```
for v in cyclic_loop(lambda: range(N)):
    print(v)
```

Comment: I'm confused. You're asking if something like this already exists, and then you show us 4 different implementations of the same thing. Why is that necessary for a yes/no question? Do you want us to review your 4 potential solutions as well?

Comment: @chepner `itertools.cycle` internally stores all the elements in some kind of container, effectively making a copy of the input iterable.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Apologies that my question wasn't clear. I though I stated, that I want to know whether something like that exists already somewhere. 

I rephrased the question. I'm open to any advice to rephrase it even further.

I thought if I don't show the three implementations and mention the advantages / disadvantages, people might point me to itertools.cycle

Comment: @Aran-Fey I also thought, that if this does not exist in an existing module, then
people might find at least a potential solution for such a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a generator

```py
def cyclical(N):
    x = 0
    while True:
        x = (x + 1) % N
        yield x

for value in cyclical(10):...
```

This is slightly more economical than the first version, since `itertools.count` will store an ever-increasing integer, while this version stores an integer between 0 and N.

Comment: This is just V1, but reimplementing `itertools.count`.

Comment: @chepner: now I think of it, it's not exactly equivalent, it might save some space for large numbers.

Comment: Compare `sys.getsizeof(1)` and `sys.getsizeof(100_000_000_000_000_000)`.

Comment: @blue_note Hmmm if nobody else knows about a built in solution I suggest, that you just add at the beginning of your answer, that you're not aware of any built in solution / library and that you suggest your solution, then  I'll mark your answer as accepted solution

Comment: @chepner: modulo with bigger numbers would be slightly slower I think. tricky to trust timeit for such short functions but for me there was about 20-25% difference

Comment: @blue_note: It seems you didn't react to my prevoius suggestion.
I'll just accept your answer and assume nobody knows of a built in solution or a pypi solution.